# SQLCipher "sqlite_3key" warning for Archiving and Profiling, No Warning for Debug

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite, sqlcipher

I've followed the documentation in the Official SQLCipher Site for iOS. I imported sqlite3.h. I added openssl and sqlcipher xode.proj. They are actually all fine.

It's encrypting the databases and I can query off them. The builds are good, except for this little warning about sqlite3_key.

I can see the step by step build process of the custom script and everything is fine.

I can see in the header file that there is that `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC` condition for this function not present in the native sqlite3 because we're using the sqlcipher version of sqlite.

I've added the `-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC` to the C Flag and C++ Flag, this is for both Project and Target Build Settings.

Overall SQLCipher works fine except for this warning:

> Implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_key' is invalid in C99

that keeps popping up during Profiling and Archiving the Binary in Xcode.

Building it via Debug doesn't throw this warning.

Is there anything that I still have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (still) assume that you have some build setting different between Debug and Release configuration (e.g. "Header Search Path"). If you can't find the problem in the Build Settings, I would recommend to inspect the preprocessed output of the source file:

- Select the .m file that gives the warning.
- Choose Product -> Generate Output -> Preprocessed File from the Xcode menu.
- At the bottom of the preprocessed output window, switch between

  - "Running" (which uses the Debug configuration by default) and
  - "Profiling" (which uses the Release configuration).

In the preprocessed output, search for the `sqlite3_key()` declaration in both versions. You can also check if the correct version of "sqlite3.h" was included. Without a Header Search Path, there would be a line

```
# 1 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h" 1 3 4
```

With the Header Search Path correctly set up for SQLCipher, the path to "sqlite3.h" should be different, so you can check that and again compare "Running/Debug" and "Profiling/Release" output.

Comment: Hi Martin R, This is what I get:  

sqlite3_key  

Running - line 37284  
Profiling - line 37265  

Header Path  

Running:  

# 4396 "sqlcipher/sqlite3.h"
           int sqlite3_key(
  sqlite3 *db,
  const void *pKey, int nKey
);

Profiling:  

- There's nothing.  


So I tried removing: -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 from Release and now it's okay in Profiling.  

Is this okay? Is this Flag important?

Comment: Oh, So Here's the Problem: If I leave it at Any Architecture|Any SDK for -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1, It Flags that Warning. But if I choose at least Any iOS SDK, it now works with -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1. Thanks for all the help Martin, It's all good now!